# ASP repeater showing some duplicate returns

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I run a simple query and bind it to a repeater however, **SOME** of the data is coming twice, data isn't duplicated in the db. This is happening when I oderby and take. I've adjusted my code as MSDN has, but maybe I've missed something?

The code:

```
var query = (from q in data.Events
                         join x in data.Types on q.id equals x.id
                         where q.change != "UNCHANGED" && q.indicator.Contains("UP")
                         select new
                         {
                             q.id,
                             q.price,
                             q.date,
                             q.indicator,
                             x.information

                         }).ToList().OrderByDescending(q => q.price).Take(10);
            rptEvents.DataSource = query;
            rptEvents.DataBind();
```

Comment: If you run the SQL query that that generates on the database, do you get duplicate rows?

Comment: @John No duplicates there. Out of my 10, 3 are duplicates when using LINQ. The 3rd, 5th, and 8th positions seem to duplicate no matter how I select the data, so if the data is different, it still causes the issue.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `.OrderByDescending(q => q.price).Take(10).ToList()` ? Your query is loading everything into memory, then running `OrderBy().Take()` and binding to an IEnumerable.

Comment: JOIN to `data.Types` produces duplications. It's obvious.